# Upload multiple files with a php script

Tags: php, upload

I've been modify this php script but it won't work, it always fail. It managed to create the folder, but it fails to move the files from the temporary folder to the right one, the function move_uploaded_file return always false. This is the code:

```
<?php
include 'connection.php';
include '../empty.html'; 
session_start();

if(isset($_FILES['filearray'])){
    $name_array = $_FILES['filearray']['name'];
    $tmp_name_array = $_FILES['filearray']['tmp_name'];
    $type_array = $_FILES['filearray']['type'];
    $size_array = $_FILES['filearray']['size'];
    $error_array = $_FILES['filearray']['error'];

    $titlealbum=$_POST['titoloalbum']; 
    $username=$_SESSION['username']; 
    $path="../users/".$username."/".$titlealbum."/"; 
    echo $path;
    mkdir($path,0777);    

    $total=count($tmp_name_array);
    for($i=0; $i<$total; $i++){
        $rightpath=$path.$name_array[$i];
        if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name_array[$i], $rightpath)){
                echo $name_array[$i]." upload is complete<br>";
                echo "upload completato"; 
        } else {
            echo "move_uploaded_file function failed for ".$name_array[$i]." into".$path."<br>";
        }
    }
}
else
echo "Files not found";
?>
```

This is the html form:

```
  <form id="albumform" style="display:none"  enctype="multipart/form-data" action="scripts/albumupload.php" multiple="multiple"  method="POST">
      <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000000">
      Name: <input name="titoloalbum" type="text" required><br><br>
      Cover: <input name="userfile" type="file">
     <br><br>Select your songs:<br />
     <input name="filearray[]" type="file" value="10000000" /><br />
     <input name="filearray[]" type="file" value="10000000"/><br />
     <input name="filearray[]" type="file" value="10000000"/><br />
     <input name="filearray[]" type="file" value="10000000"/><br />
     <input type="submit" value="Send files" />
    </form>
```

I know that this form kinda sucks, but i don't like the multiple selection with a signle "input". Thanks in advice

Comment: echo `$tmp_name_array[$i]` and check what it return

Comment: Echo and check values of `$tmp_name_array[$i]` and `$rightpath` on every iteration.

Comment: 'tmp_name array result:
rightpath result: ../users/test2/TEST/test.mp3'. As you can see the tmp array_name is empty.

Comment: Its nice that you bothered to capture the error code, `$error_array = $_FILES['filearray']['error'];` but it would be really useful to actually check it as well

Comment: It displays 'Error Array: 1'

Comment: Why so many file types with same name in the form ?

Comment: Because the first (userfile) fiile must be a image that i'll add to the script later and the others (filearray[]) files must be mp3. I would prefer to manage these file with different variable names

Answer (score 0):

You have error in your code :

```
$total=count($tmp_name_array);
```

change this to

```
$total=count($name_array);
```

*You are using count function with wrong varia*ble.

**Also remove so many file types with same name from the form. Either name them different.**

```
<input name="filearray[]" type="file" value="10000000"/><br />
```

Comment: It stills don't work. this is the result: 
tmp_name array result:
rightpath result: ../users/test2/Test2/test.mp3
Error Array:1                                                                                                     I don't understand why the tmp_name_array is empty

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following commented algorithm for Multiple-Files upload:

**PHP**

```
    <?php
        // FILENAME: albumupload.php
        include 'connection.php';
        include '../empty.html';
        session_start();


        $filesArray     = isset( $_FILES['filesArray'] ) ? $_FILES['filesArray']        : null;
        $titleAlbum     = isset($_POST['titoloalbum'])   ? isset($_POST['titoloalbum']) : null;
        $arrFilesData   = array();

        if( $filesArray && !empty($filesArray) ){
            $arrFilesKeys       = array_keys($filesArray['name']);
            $arrFilesNames      = $filesArray['name'];
            $arrFilesTypes      = $filesArray['type'];
            $arrFilesTmpNames   = $filesArray['tmp_name'];
            $arrFilesErrors     = $filesArray['error'];
            $arrFilesSizes      = $filesArray['size'];

            foreach($arrFilesKeys as $intKey=>$strKeyName){
                $tempFileData               = new stdClass();
                $tempFileData->key          = $strKeyName;
                $tempFileData->name         = $arrFilesNames[$strKeyName];
                $tempFileData->type         = $arrFilesTypes[$strKeyName];
                $tempFileData->tmp_name     = $arrFilesTmpNames[$strKeyName];
                $tempFileData->error        = $arrFilesErrors[$strKeyName];
                $tempFileData->error        = $arrFilesSizes[$strKeyName];
                $arrFilesData[$strKeyName]  = $tempFileData;
            }

            // UPLOAD THE FILES:
            if($titleAlbum){
                $username   = trim($_SESSION['username']);
                $path       =  __DIR__ . "/../users/" . $username . "/" . $titleAlbum;

                //CREATE UPLOAD DIRECTORY IF IT DOESN'T ALREADY EXIST...
                if(!file_exists($path)){
                    mkdir($path,    0777, TRUE);
                }

                // LOOP THROUGH THE FILES OBJECT ARRAY AND PERFORM FILE-UPLOAD
                foreach($arrFilesData as $fileKey=>$objFileData){
                    $rightPath      = $path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $objFileData->name;
                    if(move_uploaded_file($objFileData->tmp_name, $rightPath)){
                        echo $objFileData->name . " upload is complete<br>";
                        echo "upload completato";
                    } else {
                        echo "move_uploaded_file function failed for ". $objFileData->name ." into". $path . "<br>";
                    }

                }
            }

        }
```

In this case, your HTML Form is expected to look like this:

**HTML**

```
        <form id="albumform" style=""  enctype="multipart/form-data" action="scripts/albumupload.php" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000000">
            Name: <input    name = "titoloalbum" type="text" required><br><br>
            Cover: <input   name = "filesArray[userfile]" type="file">
            <br><br>Select your songs:<br />
            <input name="filesArray[file_1]" type="file" value="" /><br />
            <input name="filesArray[file_2]" type="file" value=""/><br />
            <input name="filesArray[file_3]" type="file" value=""/><br />
            <input name="filesArray[file_4]" type="file" value=""/><br />
            <input type="submit" value="Send files" />
        </form>
```